# Filtering Smarttables initial read request

Tags: odata, sapui5

im using a sap Smarttable to display my data from an ABAP Backend server. Additionally im using SmartVariantManagement to apply Variants and make them persistent.

The problem in my Application is the initial Load of the Smarttable. It seems like the table is first loading all the available data without any filters from the inital Variant of my Smartvariantmanagement.

Is there any way to apply the filters of Smartvariantmanagement to the initial Load in the Smarttable?

Or even better: Is it possible to shut down a running odata-read request if i apply a new selection in the smartfilterbar and just run the new one instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## example 1:

you can avoid the initial request by the smarttable property

```
enableAutoBinding="false"
```

you can also set some mandatory fields for filtering, now the user performces an explicit call to the database

## example 2:

you can also define a filter in the smarttable function

```
beforeRebindTable="onBeforeRebindTable"
```

controller:

```
    onBeforeRebindTable: function (oEvent) {
        var oBindingParams = oEvent.getParameter("bindingParams");

        oBindingParams.filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("PropertyX", "EQ", "myProperty"));
    }
```

regards